# Reasonable valid start address for mmap address hint so as to be gauranteed that things work

Tags: mmap, virtual-address-space

In one of our assignments we are required to build a distributed shared memory between 2 machines, I was using a paging based technique such that the base addresses are different on both the machines. But there is this linked list test case which almost mandates that both address ranges are same. mmap's fixed address using MAP_FIXED causes the slave machine to crash( because the stack of the reply server thread was getting overwritten ), i figured that creating an address that is gauranteed to be free at the very start during initialization on both processes would be reasonable. However, after hours of scouring the net i am still unlucky in finding that default address. Our requirement is 10000 pages. If someone could point the base of heap address beyond which sbrk is gauranteed not to grow i could use that.

Best,
Subramanian

Comment: This is going to be very much not portable. You should specify not only which operating system you are interested in but also the architecture. It might even depend on the kernel version!

Comment: Oh, Centos,  2.6.32 64 bit machine, As an aside, I came across this RLIMIT_DATA cur_limit entry. It says 4 GB!!!! Even though I had mentioned -m32 in my compiler flags. I have searched a lot for RLIMIT_DATA on a 32 bit machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that anyone is going to be able to guarantee any address that will always work. The choice of virtual addresses is always up to the kernel and `MAP_FIXED` is always going to step on its toes.

Might I suggest not using `-m32` to compile your application? With so many more addresses available you'll be 4294967296 times less likely to hit a conflict if you choose a random address.

I would suggest one of the following hacks:

- Since you are on Linux, read and parse `/proc/self/maps`. Find the largest gap between any two mappings, and choose an address right at the midpoint of this gap. You should be reasonably safe in case the previous mapping creeps upward or the next mapping creeps downward in subsequent runs. Communicate this address to the other process so that it can try mapping at the same address. Hopefully the other process's memory map will be similar enough and it will have this big gap more or less at the same place.
- Temporarily allocate a huge amount of anonymous memory without `MAP_FIXED`. For your fixed mapping, try the address immediately following this mapping. Communicate this address to the other process so that it can try mapping at the same address, and then get rid of the temporary mapping. Hopefully the other process's memory map will be similar enough and you've left yourself a huge amount of spare addresses before your chosen address so that if the second process is occupying some of those you will still be OK.

And keep in mind that these are hacks.

Comment: Actually the makefile was given by the course instructor LOL and since we are implementing a distributed shared memory it comes right at the beginning of the initialization, in that case my /proc/self/maps will be only data section, bss, cs and stack right? and most likely i will choose something between the heap and stack.

Comment: `/proc/self/maps` will contain data, bss, cs, stack, heap, shared libraries, and any other mapped files that are already established by the time you query it. On my system the big gap happens to be between the heap and the mapping for libc.

Comment: I am using RLIMIT_DATA and getrlimit to get the max bound of the heap. However, on 64-bit Linux machine, which is there in my lab, getrlimit returns 4GB which is way past the 32 bit address space, I am using in my 32 bit application. Yes I will try to use your technique.