# Error with mmap and MAP_FIXED for allocating custom memory address

Tags: memory-management, segmentation-fault, mmap

This software

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include<iostream>

main(){
    int* p;
    //int* p = 0x9;
    std::cout << p << std::endl;
    int* memptr = mmap((void*) p, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANON|MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED, -1, 0);
    std::cout << memptr << std::endl;
    std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
    std::cout << *memptr << std::endl;
    std::cout << memptr << std::endl;
    *memptr = 345;
    std::cout << *memptr << std::endl;
    std::cout << memptr << std::endl;   
}
```

gives a segmentation fault (compiled on Linux with -fpermissive) when MAP_FIXED is given to mmap

```
0x7fff507b0dd0
0xffffffffffffffff
-------------------------
Speicherzugriffsfehler (Speicherabzug geschrieben)
```

on the contrary without MAP_FIXED I obtain

```
0x7fffee5ce2d0
0x7f4f506ab000
-------------------------
0
0x7f4f506ab000
345
0x7f4f506ab000
```

but I want that memptr points to an allocated memory region starting in the location pointed to by p (see mmap call. For this reason I tried MAP_FIXED flag).
Moreover I want that this location is specified by the user as a number as it happens when I uncomment the pointer initialization, obtaining:

```
//int* p;
int* p = 0x9;
```

So I want that after

```
 int* memptr = mmap((void*) p, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANON|MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED, -1, 0);
```

or

```
int* memptr = mmap((void*) p, sizeof(int), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANON|MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED, -1, 0);
```

memptr points to 0x9 where 4096 or sizeof(int) bytes respectively are allocated and available for writing via

```
*memptr = 345;
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0x9 is unlikely to be within a writable - or even allocatable - range of addresses.  For example, http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/anatomy-of-a-program-in-memory/ shows a process's address space in Linux where the lowest segment - text - starts at 0x08048000, with nothing below that.  http://lwn.net/Articles/91829/ describes in more detail which addresses might be accessible with `mmap`.  See also: [Reasonable valid start address for mmap address hint so as to be gauranteed that things work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112877/reasonable-valid-start-address-for-mmap-address-hint-so-as-to-be-gauranteed-that)